# How to solve "Started user manager for UID 120" in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, wine, grubrescue

I have installed `Ubuntu18.04` on Intel NUC. It has been running fine for years. Few days back, I installed `wine` to run some `exe` in ubuntu. After that, when I rebooted my system, it got stuck at boot up with following error message:

[image]

I have gone through many post already on this, and many of them suggest to enter into recovery mode by pressig `shift` + `esc`. When I do this, it loads me into this

[image]

In order to resolve this, I have followed some post where, I have done following steps:

`Step 1: grub> ls`
(hd0), (hd0,gpt1), (hd0,gpt2)

`Step 2: grub> set prefix=(hd0,2)/grub`

`Step 3: grub> set root=(hd0,2)`

`Step 4: grub> insmod linux`

`Step 5: grub> insmod normal`

`Step 6: grub> normal`

After this steps, it still stays at `grub>`

`Step 7: grub> sudo update-grub`

but it shows error `'sudo' command not found`

I have repeated the above steps for `(hd0,gpt1)` but nothing happended. How can I move out of this.

Comment: @guiverc Appologies, I have made changes, its Ubuntu18.04

Comment: @guiverc I have updated the question. After running `insmod normal` and `normal` it still stays at `grub>` screen and do not boots up

Comment: It looks like gdm3 is having trouble starting. Can you disable the graphical boot target, by highlighting the Ubuntu boot option in GRUB and pressing e, then replacing `quiet splash` with `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`, and then pressing Ctrl+X? This will boot to a login: prompt where you can enter your username.  When logged in, can you `systemctl start gdm`, and then run `systemctl status gdm`?

Comment: You might need to switch to a new virtual console using Ctrl+Alt+F2 or another console (F3, F4…)

Comment: @galexite `Can you disable the graphical boot target, by highlighting the Ubuntu boot option in GRUB` Sorry didnt get you, how do I highligh Ubuntu boot?

Comment: The option is highlighted when the Ubuntu option is inside the white rectangle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128407/discussion-between-galexite-and-s-andrew).